# When should I write an implementation of the Drop trait for a type?

Tags: memory-management, rust, traits

I am going through [the too many lists book](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/) which explains the basics of Rust by writing some linked lists. In [this chapter](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/first-drop.html), the author explains why we might want to implement the `Drop` trait for our custom type stating that the automatic handling of the destructor is **bad** for that type.

That's all well and good, but why and when should I implement the `Drop` trait for my own custom types? I wouldn't have guessed it was even needed for the above scenario (as mentioned in the book). When should I let Rust handle the destructors on it's own?

Comment: The same reason you'd write code at any other time - when you need to do something that isn't the default behavior. In this case, the default behavior is recursively calling `drop` on all the contained items.

Comment: Note that in the book's scenario, what generally happens is that one day you handle a slightly bigger list than usual, things blow up, and looking at the memory dump you realize that there is an unbounded recursion here that needs fixing. Then you implement `Drop` yourself.

Comment: @Shepmaster: it’s not the *default* behaviour, it’s the *only* behaviour. Implementing `Drop` is all about doing something else *as well*. (OK, so you can mutate `self` to change what will happen with the contained objects, so you can make something which effectively prevents `Drop` from happening by wrapping an `Option` and replacing some value with `None`, but I maintain my position.)